# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'NoneType'

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a list that I am inserting numbers into when I try to add the numbers I get an error TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'NoneType'
Not really sure why.  Here is my code

```
smallWindow = Window()
smallList = smallWindow.size(3)
print smallList

position = 0
sum = 0
for arg in sys.argv[1:]:
    smallList.pop(position)
    smallList.insert(0, int(arg))
    print smallList
    print smallWindow.max(smallList)
    position+=1
    if position  == 3:
        position = 0
    sum = 0
    for number in smallList:
        sum += number
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `None` in `smallList`, and operand `+=` won't work for this way - `number` must have to be an `int`, right now you are having:

```
int += None
```